# Как сделать прыжок от стены в платформере на Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Здраствуйте)
Делаю свою первую игру на Unity. 2d платформер.
При написании кода для прыжка от стены столкнулся с проблемой. Все работает, но прыжок совершается вертикально вверх, хотя должен отталкиваться от стены.
Сперва упраление по Х происходило с помощью `Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")`, но узнал, что лучше отслеживать движение условием. Вместо velocity применял AddForce, комментировал участки кода, которые теоретически могли конфликтовать. Результатов нет. Правда в некоторых случаях персонажа раз из 10-20 прыжков телепортировало на расстояние от стены.

Заранее извеняюсь за качество кода

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float maxSpeed;
    public float jumpForse;

    private Rigidbody2D theRB;

    public Transform groundCheckPoint;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    private bool isGrounded;

    private Animator anim;
    public SpriteRenderer playerSR;

    public float hangTime = .2f;
    private float hangCounter;
    public float jumpBufferLength = .03f;
    private float jumpBufferCount;
    private bool isFacingRight = true;

       

    public float hangTimeForWall = .2f;
    private float hangCounterForWall;
    public float wallJumpBufferLength = .03f;
    private float wallJumpBufferCount;
    public float wallJumpSpeedX;
    public float wallJumpForse;
    private float wallJumpFaceDirection = -1;

    public bool isTouchingWall;
    public Transform wallCheck;
    public float wallCheckDistance;
    private bool isWallSliding;
    public float isWallSlidingSpeed;



    void Start()
    {
        theRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    
    void Update()
    {
        
        CheckMovementDirection(); 

        

        //Проверка, на земле ли игрок
        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheckPoint.position, .2f, whatIsGround);
        CheckIfWallSliding();
        
        
        
        //managehangtime
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            hangCounter = hangTime;
        }else
        {
            hangCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

        //Буфер прыжков
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            jumpBufferCount = jumpBufferLength;
           
        }
        else
        {
            jumpBufferCount -= Time.deltaTime;
            
        }

        // Прыжок
        if(jumpBufferCount >= 0 && hangCounter > 0f && !isWallSliding)
        {
            theRB.velocity = new Vector2(theRB.velocity.x, jumpForse);
            jumpBufferCount = 0;
        }
        

        
        //СКОЛЬЖЕНИЕ ПО СТЕНЕ И ПРЫЖОК ОТ СТЕНЫ

        isTouchingWall = Physics2D.Raycast(wallCheck.position, transform.right, wallCheckDistance, whatIsGround);

        if (isWallSliding)
        {
            if (theRB.velocity.y < -isWallSlidingSpeed)
            {
                theRB.velocity = new Vector2(theRB.velocity.x, -isWallSlidingSpeed);
                
            }
        }
        
        
        if (isWallSliding)
        {
            hangCounterForWall = hangTimeForWall;
        }
        else
        {
            hangCounterForWall -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
        
        //Буфер прыжков от стены
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            wallJumpBufferCount = wallJumpBufferLength;
            
        }
        else
        {
            wallJumpBufferCount -= Time.deltaTime;

        }


        //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!ЭТО САМ ПРЫЖОК ОТ СТЕНЫ!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

        if (wallJumpBufferCount >= 0 && hangCounterForWall > 0f)
        {
// этот способ я попробовал сперва
            //theRB.velocity = new Vector2(theRB.velocity.x*wallJumpSpeedX * wallJumpFaceDirection, wallJumpForse); 
            

            Vector2 forceToAdd = new Vector2(theRB.velocity.x * wallJumpSpeedX * wallJumpFaceDirection, wallJumpForse);
            theRB.AddForce(forceToAdd, ForceMode2D.Impulse); 
            
          

         wallJumpBufferCount = 0;
        }
    }

    private void CheckMovementDirection()
    {
        if(isFacingRight && Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            Flip();
        }
        else if(!isFacingRight && Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            Flip();
        }
    }
    
    // Разворот
    private void Flip()
    {
        if(!isWallSliding)
        {
            isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
            transform.Rotate(0.0f, 180.0f, 0.0f);
            wallJumpFaceDirection *= -1;
        }
    }
    
    //Проверка на скольжение по стене
    private void CheckIfWallSliding()
    {
        if(isTouchingWall && !isGrounded && theRB.velocity.y < 0)
        {
            isWallSliding = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isWallSliding = false;
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //Бег
        if(Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            theRB.velocity = new Vector2(maxSpeed, theRB.velocity.y);
        }
        else if(Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            theRB.velocity = new Vector2(-maxSpeed, theRB.velocity.y);
        }
        else 
        {
            theRB.velocity = new Vector2(0, theRB.velocity.y);
        }
        
        //Замедление персонажа на пике прыжка
        if (!isGrounded && theRB.velocity.y < 10 && theRB.velocity.y > -10)
        {
            theRB.gravityScale = 6;
        }
        else
        {
            theRB.gravityScale = 10;
        }
        if (!isGrounded)
        {
            maxSpeed = 10;
        }
        else
        {
            maxSpeed = 8;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: google -> wall jump пробовал?

Comment: Искал разные реализации этой механики и в гугле и на ютубе, и в русскоязычном и в англоязычном. Ситуация не изменилась. Наверное, какой-то участок кода все-же мешает перемещению персонажа по Х при прыжке от стены, но какой я не понимаю

Comment: а дебаг что говорит?) Какое конкретно значение проходит неправильно что стрыбок идет вертикальный вместо горизонтального?

Comment: Хз правильно или нет, но я поставил точку останова на функции с прыжком от стены, посмотрел какие значения получаются, понял что умножая скорость по х на velocity.x я по сути умножаю на 0. Исправил, изменений нет. AddForce выводится "(10.0, 26.5)".Но я ещё поищу как проводить такой дебаг.

Answer (score 2):

С дебагом я управляться ещё не умею, но коментить все участки кода по очереди додумался. Короче, проблема оказалась в том, что участок кода с бегом конфликтовал с прыжком от стены.  Если сделать прыжок от стены и бег с помощью AddForce, то все работает, но движение через AddForce оставлять не хотелось бы. Слишком неуправляемый персонаж получается.